# Save data to a particular cell with vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

On sheet1 I have a cell that displays notes I have one cell with a drop down list for years and another with a drop down that has the months.  The third cell displays the notes for the year and month.  I built the cod to display the correct month and years notes.  what I would like to know how to do is once the notes appear in the cell I would like to be able to changed the notes or add to the notes then have that saved to the table it is pulling from so if I go back to that month and years notes it shows up with the changes.    Here is the code that pulls the information from the other sheet and displays it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

        If Range(Year, Month) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Year, Month)) Is Nothing Then

        Range("E14").Formula = [VLOOKUP(F6,'Super Admin'!A1118:M1221,MATCH(J6,'Super Admin'!A1118:M1118,0),0)]
        Range("E14").Activate
        SendKeys "{F2}"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Range("E14").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F6,'Super Admin'!A1118:M1221,MATCH(J6,'Super Admin'!A1118:M1118,0),0)]`". Side note: `Range("E14").Activate` is superfluous

Comment: No that does not work      I can get E14 to display the results of the v look up  what I need now is the cell that excel is getting the information to display in the vlookup needs to be changed when E14 text changes

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58738824/edit) to include sample data and expected outcome?